# Supported replacement for uw-imap client library

Tags: open-source, library, c++, c, imap

Looking for an open-source C/C++ imap client library, along the lines of capabilities found in [c-client library from UW](https://www.washington.edu/imap/), but with active support and development. UW one seems to be dead - even its download links are returning "not found" and latest release is 10 years old.

Comment: I use https://github.com/dinhvh/libetpan (with some custom modifications) and it works pretty well